# In Vim, how can I prevent chdir to buffer directory from running when I switch to terminal pane?

Tags: vim, terminal, chdir

In my `.vimrc`, I have:

```
autocmd BufEnter * :lchdir %:p:h
```

which changes the current directory to the directory for the file being edited in that window.

With the `terminal` feature enabled, however, I get the following messages:

> ```
> Error detected while processing BufEnter Autocommands for "*":
> E344: Can't find directory "C:\Users\sinan\!C:\WINDOWS\system32" in cdpath
> E472: Command failed
> ```

which then have to be dismissed by pressing enter. This makes it annoying to switch back & forth between a document window and terminal.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: In Vim, switching to terminal causes chdir error]

I understand why I get the error. I am trying to figure out how I need to change the `autocmd` line above so it doesn't run for terminal panes. That is, instead of `*`, I need to specify *not a terminal*.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check `'buftype'` to see if it is a terminal buffer.

```
augroup AutoChdir
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter * if &buftype !=# 'terminal' | lchdir %:p:h | endif
augroup END
```

NOTE: I have not tested this. Use as is.

See `:h 'buftype'` for more information

Comment: Or just be lazy and `:silent lchdir...` :) (Though checking is definitely the better way)